# Why is a wildcard certificate being allowed for a site with no subdomain?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

[Wildcard certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for *.company.com are not supposed to be valid for company.com. Yet [familysearch.org](https://familysearch.org/) uses a wildcard certificate *.familysearch.org.

Neither Chrome, Firefox, IE, wget, nor curl complain about it. Why? Interestingly, [cfhttp](/questions/tagged/cfhttp) does complain. Who's correct?

curl snippet:

```
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; postalCode=84150; ST=Utah; L=Salt Lake City; street=50 East North Temple Street; O=Intellectual Reserve Inc.; OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard; CN=*.familysearch.org
*        start date: 201
*        expire date: 201
*        subjectAltName: familysearch.org matched
*        issuer: C=G
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
```

Chrome screenshot:

[image]

cfhttp error:

```
Charset [empty string] 
ErrorDetail I/O Exception: Name in certificate `*.familysearch.org' does not match host name `familysearch.org' 
Filecontent Connection Failure 
Header  [empty string] 
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file. 
Responseheader  struct [empty]

Statuscode  Connection Failure. Status code unavailable. 
Text    YES
```

Comment: I think you've got your first sentence backwards...

Comment: @lc. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate in question has a [Subject Alternative Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) (SAN) of `familysearch.org`. Therefore the certificate is valid for *both* `*.familysearch.org` and `familysearch.org`.

FYI, curl is actually letting you know this, with the line:

> subjectAltName: familysearch.org matched